# How to ask "Is there exactly one element satisfying condition" in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Quick question, what's the preferable way to programmaticaly ask "Is there exactly one element in this sequence that satisfies X condition?" using Linq?

i.e.

```
// Pretend that the .OneAndOnlyOne() method exists
int[] sequence = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 };
Assert.IsTrue(sequence.OneAndOnlyOne(x => x == 2);
Assert.IsFalse(sequence.OneAndOnlyOne(x => x == 1);
```

something like this can be done with:

```
sequence.SingleOrDefault(x => x == 2) != null;
```

but that's a little clunky.

I suppose I could roll my own extension method, but this seems to be a common pattern in my code and I want to make sure there's a good clean way to do it.  Is there a way using the built-in LINQ methods?

Comment: `SingleOrDefault` will throw an InvalidOperationException: if there's more than one match.

Comment: I'd recommend IsLone() as a possible alternative name for the extension method. You're also doing 2 things with the same function, filtering and then detecting if there is only 1 element. I would do: sequence.Where(x => x == 2).IsLone()

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You could do:

```
bool onlyOne = source.Where(/*condition*/).Take(2).Count() == 1
```

Which will prevent count from enumerating a large sequence unnecessarily in the event of multiple matches.

Comment: +1, and I wish I could give you another +1 for the `.Take(2)` portion (as that very much makes sense.)

Comment: heh, I kinda like that.  I'll probably alias that behind my own extension method.

Comment: Why do you take 2 elements? What sense is behind that? ;)

Comment: If there was no .Take(2), Count() would iterate through the whole collection counting how many elements there are. If there are many, or even an infinite number of items in the collection it will take a long/infinite amount of time. With the .Take(2) it will iterate over at most 2 items.

Comment: Why not use bool onlyOne = source.Count(/*condition*/) == 1?

Comment: @Tobias - Because `Count` must find all matching elements before the comparison can be done. Using `Take(2)` prevents you from finding more matches than you need to. If you're trying to find exactly `n` matches, you can fail as soon as you find `n+1` matches.

Comment: Love the `Take(2)` trick!

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way is to just use [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx). Single won't work for you, because it throws an exception if there isn't just that single element.

LBushkin suggests (in the comments) to use [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal.aspx) to compare a sequence with another one. You could use that by skipping the first element with Skip(1), and comparing the resulting sequence to an empty sequence such as what you can get from [Empty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, but if my .OneAndOnlyOne() method runs on a sequence and hits a 2nd element that satisfies the predicate - it can return false right away.  Count() will enumerate the entire sequence

Comment: That is true, but going "beyond" Count might be a case of premature optimization - depending on your needs, of course. If you want to prevent that, you could use .Skip(1) and see if you get an empty sequence.

Comment: @Michael: You don't need to use Count. You can use `SequenceEqual()` which handles empty sequences just fine without throwing exceptions. And, you can always roll your own extension method ... not that it's really necessary for the OP's use case.

Comment: Huh. Didn't even know that existed (probably because I've never needed it). I'll update. As for the extension method: of course you could write one, but you still need to know how to write it, and as far as I'm aware, it's not really feasible to write one from scratch (that is, not using the existing LINQ methods).

Answer (score 2):

You could use this extension method, which I think should have been included in the standard extension methods for linq:

```
public static int CountUpTo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int maxCount) {
    if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
    if (maxCount < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxCount");

    var count = 0;
    var enumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator();
    while (count < maxCount && enumerator.MoveNext())
        count += 1;
    return count;
}
```

Used like so:

```
return sequence.CountUpTo(2) == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I had the issue to determine if exactly one item is contained I decided to create following extension. In my optionion it fits good into the set of already existing extensions (e.g.: SingleOrDefualt, FirstOrDefault ...).

```
 public static class IEnumerableExtension
{
    public static TProject OneOrDefault<TInput, TProject>(this IEnumerable<TInput> sequence, Func<TInput, TProject> projection)
    {
        var enumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator();
        bool firstMoveNext = enumerator.MoveNext();
        TInput current = enumerator.Current;
        if (firstMoveNext && !enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            return projection(current);
        }
        else
        {
            return default;
        }
    }
}
```