# How can I get the first value of an IEnumerable iff the length is exactly one, or default otherwise?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, ienumerable, extension-methods

I would like something like `IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault`, but I would like the default value returned if `length != 1`. Something like `v.Count() == 1 ? v[0] : default`. But I would prefer to do it without converting the entire enumerable into an array. What is the best way to get this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a good idea to avoid iterating the enumerable more than once as not all enumerables repeat the same values.

In order to ensure that your enumerable only returns 1 element it is the most efficient to take the first two elements from the enumerable and convert the result into an array. If the array then has two elements you know that the enumerable has more than one element without iterating the entire enumerable. It is possible for an enumerable to be infinitely long.

So here's how to do it:

```
public static T OneOnlyThenFirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var beginning = source.Take(2).ToArray();
    return beginning.Length == 1 ? beginning[0] : default(T);
}
```

Comment: Is converting to an array necessary? Based on [this answer to a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1993398/2137382) I think you can just check if the `Take(2).Count() == 1`, and if so, return `source.Single()`.

Comment: @JoeSewell - Converting to an array is necessary. If you do `.Take(2).Count()` and then `.Single()` you are iterating the enumerable twice and there's no guarantee that an enumerable always produces the same values each time.

Comment: Some enumerables might even fail the second time through.

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft's implementation of [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/8087366974af11d2.html) works directly with the underlying enumerator. Yours can too:

```
public static T FirstIfOnlyOne<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T defaultValue = default(T))
{
    // (Null check and IList<T> optimization omitted...)

    using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext()) // Is there at least one item?
        {
            T item = enumerator.Current; // Save it.
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) // Is that it?
                return item;
        }
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

This is likely the most efficient implementation possible.

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to write a custom extension method, something like:

```
public static TSource MyFirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    return source.Count() == 1 ? source.First() : default(TSource);
}
```

but you need to keep in mind that methods `Count()` and `First()` will need to instantiate the inner collection of elements in order to get the count (or the first element).

Hope, that will help you.

Comment: This will throw an exception. There is no first item when count is zero. Besides that, what value is returned when source has two items?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg - thanks for the note (I fixed the typo).