# Validation multiple properties required one

Tags: c#, validation

I am looking for better way to solve following scenario. I don't want to use reflection for now and was to take logic to nth level. Code should be simple C# no attribute validations. Because this is back-end code validation.
I would love to solve this some operator like XOR or similar.

**Scenario:**

I have three fields  (can be 4, 5, nth) in a class. out of three user must select only one field either of them. if none, two or more fields are selected we need to throw exception.

**Code:**

```
// no type defined for item
if ( hasUserId==false
    && hasSigningGroup==false
    && hasAssignedAgent == false)
{
    throw new Exception("No type defined for item.");
}
else
{
    if ((hasSigningGroup && hasUserId)|| (hasSigningGroup && hasAssignedAgent)|| (hasUserId && hasAssignedAgent))
    {
        throw new Exception("User ID , Signing group or assigned agent. Only one property can be set.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use an enum instead of three bools?

Comment: Define "better"? Is current code working? What you dislike/want to change (do you want a loop instead using them directly)? *"logic to nth level"* - you didn't present that problem clearly, what is nth level? Will you have many of such properties? Are their validations similar? Can you give examples?

Comment: @Sinatr currenlty I have three Fields for that I  have to add three  OR in else statement. suppose tomorrow i have fourth field my else statement will have more OR in else statement and for five it will have many more so current solution is working but in future it will cause issues so I need better solution for this scenario.

Comment: @SomeBody I don't think Enum can work. but would love to see your solution/approach.

Comment: Now you have 3 options and only one must be selected. What if you had more than 3, how many bool conditions will you write? I think you're letting the UI dictate your design here which is a bad thing. Instead make it an enum or a set of int or string the user can select from. Then the only validation you would need is: 1) Cannot be null 2) Must be a value from the set.

Comment: @SameeDaris Why do you think an enum wouldn't work? Something like `public enum IdentifierType { None, UserId, SigningGroup, AssignedAgent }` would suffice. Then you can have a property `public IdentifierType UserIdentifierType { get; set; }`. Now, instead of setting `hasUserId` to true, you set `UserIdentifierType = IdentifierType.UserId`. And you only need to check `if (UserIdentifierType == IdentifierType.None) { throw ... }`.

Comment: "One field must be selected" is kind of easy to support. Hold them in collection (array of controls in winforms, bindings to array of bools in wpf) and then just [use linq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1993398/1997232).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed legacy code/schema has three fields USER ID fields, Group ID and assigned Agent ID. these bools are created by looking at those fields. I can't change schema to type  and if any two are filled your logic wont work. suppose if two fields are selected what will be value in UserIdentifierType ?

Comment: @Sinatr I already said this is back end code :)

Comment: Guys these are three separate properties in a class , its not a collection , Just like FirstName,MiddleName and LastName only one should be selected or should have value in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I found easy way to solve this issue .This will work in all cases. Neither XOR nor != operators were working.

```
            int result = Convert.ToInt32(hasUserId) + Convert.ToInt32(hasSigningGroup) + Convert.ToInt32(hasAssignedAgent);

            if (result != 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("User ID , Signing group or assigned agent. Please set one property.");
            }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators
Logical exclusive OR operator ^

"The ^ operator computes the logical exclusive OR, also known as the logical XOR, of its operands. The result of x ^ y is true if x evaluates to true and y evaluates to false, or x evaluates to false and y evaluates to true. Otherwise, the result is false. That is, for the bool operands, the ^ operator computes the same result as the inequality operator !=."

You could also use !=.

I believe this is what you are looking for.

Edit: removed code example due to logical flaw. Answer is still ^ or != as an XOR operator.